# Blackberry Maps closing oddly. Not Google maps

Tags: blackberry, maps

I'm having some trouble finding documentation on CLOSING a blackberry map.
My map opens, albeit with some odd marker behavior, but when you close the map it displays a clear screen.

The invoke code is quite simple, as the map request calls a new controller and within the constructor is this:

```
String document = "<location-document>... etc";
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS, new MapsArguments( MapsArguments.ARG_LOCATION_DOCUMENT, document));
```

I tried to add a close line

```
public boolean onClose() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
        return true;
    }
```

but this is not being applied to the map itself, but the page the map opened into. That's logical, I guess.

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong. I don't know of how to open a map another way, or if there is a way to have the close button close the map AND the containing screen.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a simple one line function that fixed this problem.

```
public void onExposed()
{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
}
```

Adding that to the map controller closes the map application when the user clicks the back button. Simple as that.